# Get Application Pools from multiple servers IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, frameworks

I am trying to get all application pools running on IIS7 servers.  I want to display these in a grid and allow users to start, stop, or recycle them.  This works great in IIS6 using DirectoryENtry but that does not work for IIS7.  I will have 4 or 5 servers that I will need to go through and grab all Application Pools.  Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerIP FROM Servers WHERE AppPoolIIS7='Y' AND Domain='LAN'", myConnection);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string serverIP = rdr["ServerIP"].ToString();
            ServerManager sm = new ServerManager(serverIP);
            ApplicationPoolCollection appPoolColl = sm.ApplicationPools;

            foreach (ApplicationPool appPool in appPoolColl)
            {

            }                
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }           
}
```

When stepping through the code, my first server is successfully retrieved from the database but when I try to pass serverIP to my Server Manager I get the below error.

Filename: \?\10.0.22.22
Error: Cannot read configuration file

Why is it adding the \?\ to my IP?

EDIT:  I made some changes to the code and i am getting a different error.

```
ServerManager sm = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverIP);
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with 
>   CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine
>   failed due to the following error: 800706ba

Comment: Apologies if you've already seen this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693567/comexception-during-authentication-when-managing-iis-remotely-using-microsoft-we), it's not got an accepted answer but just in case any of the suggestions there help you.

Comment: Which user is it talking about?  The user that I am running the application as?

Comment: I'd imagine so. Otherwise, I suspect it would be the computer account if it translates to a Network Service user. You'll be able to see the user details in the authentication failure event on the remote machine (if you have logon failures audited). I did also see something relating to DCOM needing to be allowed through the firewall, too, if you're not seeing anything on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ServerManager.OpenRemote` method use DCOM internally to connect to the remote server and by default ports using by DCOM is block by windows firewall. Because DCOM using TCP port 135 and dynamic range of TCP ports 1024/65335 you need to change setting of IIS Admin COM+ package on remote machine to limit its endpoint to use just one TCP port instead of dynamic range.  You can find the instruction [here](http://mvolo.com/connecting-to-iis-70-configuration-remotely-with-microsoftwebadministration/).

**Edit**

By default in the Windows 2008+ `ahadmin` pachage key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{9fa5c497-f46d-447f-8011-05d03d7d7ddc}` is `read-only` for all users but `TrustedInstaller` you must first take ownership of the key then give `full control` permission to the user who want change the `ahadmin`package settings. Remember, back the key permission setting to the original after changing the package properties.

Comment: I am walking through those instructions.  However, it looks like it is greyed out.  Probably group policy.

Comment: Taking ownership of the reg key worked great.  Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: And FYI for those wondering...You do have to restart the server after making changes to the COM objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to open the firewall, but you don't have to set a fixed port for ahadmin. You need three rules in the firewall. One to open port 135 (tcp), one for %SystemRoot%\System32\dllhost.exe with local ports set to RPC Dynamic Ports and the last for %SystemRoot%\System32\dllhost.exe with local port set to RPC Endpoint Mapper